# trying to broadcast ip camera running with python script to rtsp client

Tags: python

I'm applying this python scripts from https://github.com/stefanopini/simple-HRNet on my ip camera.

this is the command i used to launch the HRnet, and it works.

`python scripts\live-demo.py --filename rtsp://user:pass@camip/streaming/channels/1`

now i want to broadcast the camera stream along with the python script. i would like to have a client link like an rtsp link to this connection as an output so i can stream the scripted camera anywhere within my network.

can anyone give me a nudge of an idea on where to start?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), [edit] it accordingly, and it can be reopened. Thanks!